# Push Navigate from UITabbarController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am using `UITabbarController` which has three child `UIViewController` named as `FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController`, `ThirdViewController`. I have a button on `FirstViewController`. When we tap the button, it need to push navigate to FourthViewController. Here the FourthViewController navigate inside `UITabBarController` itself. But i need it navigate out of `UITabBarController` not inside.

Button Target Action

```
ForthViewController *share = [[ForthViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:share animated:YES];
```

Could anyone guide me for right way. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: "i need it navigate out of UITabbarController not inside" means?...

Comment: Goley got my point and it works. Thank you for your interest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ForthViewController *share = [[ForthViewController alloc] init];
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:share animated:YES];
```

As long as your tab bar controller is in a navigation controller, this will push your view controller on that navigation stack.